# create data frame from nested entries

Tags: r

I have a data frame `test` like this:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(X = 1L, entityId = structure(1L, .Label = "HOST-123", class = "factor"), 
    displayName = structure(1L, .Label = "server1", class = "factor"), 
    discoveredName = structure(1L, .Label = "server1", class = "factor"), 
    firstSeenTimestamp = 1593860000000, lastSeenTimestamp = 1603210000000, 
    tags = structure(1L, .Label = "c(\"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\", \"CONTEXTLESS\"), c(\"app1\", \"client\", \"org\", \"app1\", \"DATA_CENTER\", \"PURPOSE\", \"REGION\", \"Test\"), c(NA, \"NONE\", \"Host:Environment:test123\", \"111\", \"222\", \"GENERAL\", \"444\", \"555\")", class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
"entityId", "displayName", "discoveredName", "firstSeenTimestamp", 
"lastSeenTimestamp", "tags"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

There is a column called `tags` which should become a dataframe. I need to get rid of the first row in tags (which keep saying CONTEXTLESS, expand the second column in tags(make them columns. Lastly I need to insert the 3rd column values in tags under each expanded columns.

For example in needs to look like this:

```
structure(list(entityId = structure(1L, .Label = "HOST-123", class = "factor"), 
    displayName = structure(1L, .Label = "server1", class = "factor"), 
    discoveredName = structure(1L, .Label = "server1", class = "factor"), 
    firstSeenTimestamp = 1593860000000, lastSeenTimestamp = 1603210000000, 
    app1 = NA, client = structure(1L, .Label = "None", class = "factor"), 
    org = structure(1L, .Label = "Host:Environment:test123", class = "factor"), 
    app1.1 = 111L, data_center = 222L, purppose = structure(1L, .Label = "general", class = "factor"), 
    region = 444L, test = 555L), .Names = c("entityId", "displayName", 
"discoveredName", "firstSeenTimestamp", "lastSeenTimestamp", 
"app1", "client", "org", "app1.1", "data_center", "purppose", 
"region", "test"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L
))
```

I need to remove the 1st vector that keeps saying "contextless", add the second vector the columns.  Each 2nd vector value should be a column name. Last vector should be values of the newly added columns.

Comment: `test` is a corrupted data.frame, and `test$tags` is not a data.frame. Can you check whether the `test` in your question is correct?

Comment: @Axeman, I need to expand the tags cell.

Comment: Ok, but your question says "there is a column called tags which is a data frame", and it is not a data.frame. So I'm trying to figure out what you mean.

Comment: @Axeman, can you try now?

Comment: @IRTFM, the test data frame needs to look like the second data frame posted above.

Comment: Good luck. Much of that information has been lost by whatever unspecified operation produced teh corrupted results.

Comment: @IRTFM, tags column is like this: c("CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS"), c("app1", "client", "org", "app1", "DATA_CENTER", "PURPOSE", "REGION", "Test"), c(NA, "NONE", "Host:Environment:test123", "111", "222", "GENERAL", "444", "555"). I need to remove the 1st vector that keeps saying "contextles", add the second vector the columns (each 2nd vector shoulld be a column name. Last vector should be values of the newly added columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to drop the first "row" of garbage and then do a ittle cleanup of the parse-side-effects, then this might be a good place to start:

```
read.table(text=gsub("\\),", ")\n", test$tags[1]), sep=",", skip=1, #drops line
                      header=TRUE)

  c.app1 client                       org app1 DATA_CENTER  PURPOSE REGION Test.
1   c(NA   NONE  Host:Environment:test123  111         222  GENERAL    444  555)
```

The `read.table` function uses the `scan` function which doesn't know that "c(" and ")" are meaningful. The other alternative might be to try `eval(parse(text= .))` (which would know that they are enclosing vectors) on the the second and third lines, but I couldn't see a clean way to do that. I initially tried to separate the lines using strsplit, but that caused me to loose the parens.

Here's a stab at some cleanup via that addition of some more gsub operations:

```
read.table(text=gsub("c\\(|\\)","", # gets rid of enclosing "c(" and ")"
                     gsub("\\),", "\n", # inserts line breaks
                                 test$tags[1])), 
                                 sep=",",     #lets commas be parsed
                                 skip=1,      #drops line
                                 header=TRUE) # converts to colnames

  app1 client                       org app1.1 DATA_CENTER  PURPOSE REGION Test
1   NA   NONE  Host:Environment:test123    111         222  GENERAL    444  555
```

The reason for the added ".1" in the second instance of app1 is that R colnames in dataframes need to be unique unless you override that with `check.names=FALSE`

Comment: what happened to the rest of the columns like displayName discoveredName firstSeenTimestamp lastSeenTimestamp, I need those as well.

Comment: I need the rest of the columns like displayName discoveredName firstSeenTimestamp

Comment: They are simple not in the data object you provided. I think I implied earlier that you should probably be investigating the source of the confusion further up the process that resulted in this result. You should also read the introductory material for SO. I noticed that you don't generally mark answers as correct even when they clearly are. People will start ignoring your further questions if your profile looks "empty" (as it does now.)

Comment: it is in the original data set. The problem is this. Test is a data set and tags within test is nested. For each line of row in test, there is a nested item called tag. I need to expand the tags and make it part of each line.

Comment: It may have been in the original dataset (which we cannot see) but it appears to have been lost somewhere along the data manipulations (which we also cannot see). My answer to your subsequent (very slightly different) question shows how to apply the `eval(parse(text=.))` strategy that I alluded to above.

Comment: please look at the dput(test), that is the structrure of the data set. I need to expand the tags and make it part of the each row.

Comment: So you just need to `cbind.data.frame(. , .)` the first 5 columns of `test` to the results demonstrated above.

Comment: yes, but that is only one row. my data set has thousands. Each line has column called tags, tags is nested, I need to expand it and added to the data frame. Need to do this for each line.

Comment: As always the way to get tested answers is to include a sufficiently complex data structure to adequately represent the problem for testing. You have not done so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

str2dataframe <- function(txt, keep = "all") {
  # If you can confirm that all vectors are of the same length, then we can make them into columns of a data.frame
  out <- eval(parse(text = paste0("data.frame(", as.character(txt),")")))
  # rename columns as X1, X2, ...
  nms <- make.names(seq_along(out), unique = TRUE)
  if (keep == "all")
    keep <- nms
  `names<-`(out, nms)[, keep]
}

df %>% 
  mutate(
    tags = lapply(tags, str2dataframe, -1L), 
    tags = lapply(tags, function(d) within(d, X2 <- make.unique(X2)))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tags) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "X2", values_from = "X3")
```

`df` looks like this

```
> df
  X entityId displayName discoveredName firstSeenTimestamp lastSeenTimestamp
1 1 HOST-123     server1        server1        1.59386e+12       1.60321e+12
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         tags
1 c("CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS", "CONTEXTLESS"), c("app1", "client", "org", "app1", "DATA_CENTER", "PURPOSE", "REGION", "Test"), c(NA, "NONE", "Host:Environment:test123", "111", "222", "GENERAL", "444", "555")
```

Output looks like this

```
# A tibble: 1 x 14
      X entityId displayName discoveredName firstSeenTimestamp lastSeenTimestamp app1  client org                      app1.1 DATA_CENTER PURPOSE REGION Test 
  <int> <fct>    <fct>       <fct>                       <dbl>             <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>                    <chr>  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>  <chr>
1     1 HOST-123 server1     server1             1593860000000     1603210000000 NA    NONE   Host:Environment:test123 111    222         GENERAL 444    555
```